# Why do I have to reset my USB cameras after capturing images with GStreamer (4 cameras multithreaded)

Tags: python, multithreading, gstreamer

I have a python script that identifies four 13MP USB 3.0 cameras attached to my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, and launches the following GStreamer command for each in an individual thread (shown for example here is video0):

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=1 ! image/jpeg ! filesink location=/root/test0.jpg
```

Each camera's parameters is set via v4l2-ctl thusly:

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-fmt-video=width=4208,height=3120,pixelformat=MJPG
```

The first time this launches it works great. I get four nice 13MP images and no output errors from the CLI. However, if I run this again, my images start to look scrambled. Here's an example:

[image: Scrambled Image]

I can solve this problem by resetting my USB devices. (I do it via fnctl in python, but it's functionally the same as re-plugging the devices.)

Can anyone explain how I could modify my GStreamer command to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Interesting. Out of curiosity - does the behavior change when you give the format in the pipeline directly without the `v4l2-ctl` call? E.g. `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=1 ! image/jpeg, width=4208, height=3120 ! filesink location=/root/test0.jpg`.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch I just made that change - strangely, it seems to create 3 great images, but the four always is blank with the following error:      ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Failed to allocate required memory.
Additional debug info:
gstv4l2src.c(650): gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:

Comment: Uhm.. perhaps the the USB host is exhausted on memory at that point? Does selecting a lower resolution for all of them help? Does reconnecting them to a different physical hub help? You may have to check the mainboard's manual to figure out which connectors share one bus.

Comment: Oh I'm certain I'm right on the ragged edge of memory of the bus. I designed the system to be about 5% less than the max. I separated the configuration commands from the pull commands to reduce traffick of 4 processors querying the same image. I'm just curious why it always works after a reset, but not consecutively.

Comment: Are you not overwriting the old images with the new ones, by having the same file-name at `filesink` ? Can this be a reason for the scrambled image file?

Comment: I am overwriting them - Good idea - I'll test this today!

Comment: @vk_gst unfortunately no difference made!

Answer (score 1):

try adding -ev to your gst-launch command

Comment: This command informed me I'm grabbing a 4k screencap, not my 13Mp screencap! Thanks! For some reason my v4l2-ctl values aren't sticking. Need to dig into that.

Comment: try using these options to get more debug info - GST_DEBUG= x